# Retrieving images from SQL Server 2008 and displying it in a image controller of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, image, sql-server-2008

I have a table `images` in SQL Server 2008 and it contains two columns `imageid` and `image`. I am able to insert images into the `image` column using the `FileUpload` controller and image which I have converted to binary form for storing. Now I want to display the images in an image box corresponding with the image id. I am using a textbox for having the user type in the `id` and a button to execute the command for displaying.

```
public void ShowImage()
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anu"].ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select ID,Image from Images where ID=" + txtid.Text;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dreader.Read();
        Context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dreader["image"]);
        dreader.Close();
        con.Close();
}
```

This code is working fine but it loads the image in a separate page but I need to display it in a particular image box. My front end is ASP.NET. If any one knows the answer, please help me.

Comment: this is not SQL since the SQL is working. Your problem is asp.net, so change the tags accodingly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Response.Write` Store the byte array in a session

```
Session["image"]=(byte[])dreader["image"];
```

Use this as the the source of your `image`

```
byte[] imgSrc=(byte[])Session["image"]
string imgSrcStr= Convert.ToBase64String(imgSrc);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imgSrcStr);

In the view:

<img src='"<%=imageSrc%>"' />
```

Or simply do all this in your function itself instead of `Response`

Answer (score 0):

First you should really use a parameter in your query (or a stored procedure)

And you can just create an Image from the binary data and save that to the outputstream with the correct imageformat.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dreader["image"]);
var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
Context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; //or your actual imageformat
image.Save(Context.Response.OutputStream, format);
```