# save image to database in retrive it in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to save image multipal in sql server  in byte format ,and retrieve it in image tool without using httphandlar also convert it to pdf. please guid me the easy way .

I tried:

```
if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
        {
            int length = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] imgbyt = new byte[length];
            HttpPostedFile img = FileUpload2.PostedFile;
            img.InputStream.Read(imgbyt, 0, length);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.FileName);
            lbl_image.Text = filename;
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update StudData set student_image = @image, image_name= @filename where userid='" + Session["Loginname"] + "'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbyt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@filename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = filename;
            int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

It store image in sql in byte format but How I retrieve it?
please suggest me easiest way

Comment: Easiest / Efficient ?

Comment: Retrieve the image from db and use Response.Write to write it to the page

Comment: not able to assign write coz its method group

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add an image tag on your aspx page

```
<img src='"<%=imageSrc%>"' />
```

Then on the code behind page get the Base64 of the image from the byte array that will come from the db.

```
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
```

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) get error that byte convert.toBase64string(byte[],int,int) not possibal

Comment: how to read from database? byte[] bytes= sdr["student-image"].tostring();..get error

Comment: can you show me what have you done to retrieve images?  also you can refer to http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html

Comment: byte[] img = (byte[])sdr["student_image"];
                string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(img, 0, img.Length);
                lbl_image .Text  += "<img src='data:image/png;base64," + base64string + "' alt='No Image' width='200px' vspace='5px' hspace='5px' />";

Comment: but it gives error that invalid url. url is too long

Comment: please try to follow this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997003/retrieving-images-from-sql-server-2008-and-displying-it-in-a-image-controller-of

Comment: <img src='"<%=imageSrc%>"' />   this give me error that imagesrc does not exist in current contex